# Получить числа и буквы

Tags: php

Есть текст `(2ab(2ba)a)`, как получить `2ab` и `2ba`, если там могут быть другие числа и буквы?

Comment: Описать правила, по которым это нужно "получить".

Comment: @Slash [см.демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca75e4e3481c159f9214a68c7675e90d4000d6c8)